# Attach screenshots to cucumber-html-report in cypress when the step fails?

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I unfortunately can't seem to get this working, even though I have followed [How I could attach screenshots to cucumber report in cypress when the step fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790677/how-i-could-attach-screenshots-to-cucumber-report-in-cypress-when-the-step-fails)

How can I resolve this?

I am using cypress-cucumber-processer and cucumber-html-reporter

Comment: You've not indicated how this question is not a duplicate of the other one, and so thus it presently will be treated as a duplicate. Can you write the question from first principles, i.e. what code you have, and what problem you have? If you can indicate in the post _how_ it is different from that problem, then it is appropriate to post a new question.

Comment: Aside from the duplication issue, there is not enough detail to help you anyway. "Doesn't work" is not, unfortunately, a sufficiently detailed fault report. If you can edit your post, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cytorus](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/cytorus) to write cucumber/gherkin tests using Cypress. This is how you can configure to see screenshot for failing steps in reports;

1. Setup project using [cytorus-boilerplate](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/cytorus-boilerplate).
2. This will also set up "cytorus-reporter".
3. Open `config/cucumberReport.js` and change `screenshot: false` to `screenshot: true`.
   This will generate the report with screenshots for failing steps
4. Now setup some report viewer tool like cucumber-html-reporter. Check [this](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/cytorus/blob/master/test-repository/cucumber-report-reader.js) for configuration